# Best method for separation of ADMIN and USERS entries in a database table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

lets say i have separate table for users and admins

```
users : username , password , email , name 
admins : username , password , level
```

now i have a table that both users and admins can insert data in ... like a website for selling books :

```
books : title , price
```

so 3  methods comes to mind

**method 1** - adding 2 filds to books table for admin and user

```
books : title , price , user_id , admin_id 
----> some title , 1000 , 5 , -1  // user posted book
----> some other title , 2000 , -1 , 12   // admin posted book
```

when user insert a book i'll save his `id` in `user_id` and put `-1` for `admin_id`and vise versa for admin

**method 2** - saving `user_id = -1` for admin entries

```
books : title , price , user_id 
----> some title , 1000 , 5  // user posted book
----> some other title , 2000 , -1    // admin posted book
```

**method 3** - having a user in the users table to represent admins and save all admin entries with this user id -- which doesn't feel like smart thing to do !

```
users : id , username , password 
----> 1    , admin  , adminpassword 
----> 2    ,user1  , userpassword   
----> 3    ,user2  , userpassword   

books : title , price , user_id 
----> some title , 1000 , 1  // admin posted book
----> some other title , 2000 , 2    // user posted book
----> some other title , 2000 , 3    // user posted book
```

is there any other way to do this ? which one is more acceptable approach ?

*i know we can have both users and admins in the same table and have separate `user_rules` or `user_meta` table for admins users but i dont want to use that design .... im working on a project that already been online for a year or 2 with lots of data in the database  ... the original programmer is not available and im adding some new features to the website ... im trying to avoid changing the current structure as much as possible*

Comment: "i know we can have both users and admins in the same table ... but i dont want to use that design" - That's the way I'd do it.

Comment: A person's role should be associated with the person. In other words I'd do it like @Mike

Comment: Interested in understanding why you don't want the same-table/view design. BTW `null` could be a good substitute for `-1` here

Comment: BTW - this question fits this close reason: "Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.
"

Comment: If you would at least edit your answer and explain why you don't want to use just one single table it might be a bit easier to be objective about it, but in the meantime I agree with @JayBlanchard. However likely any reason you give would indicate you have a problem somewhere else too, so either way I doubt I would recommend any of the 3 options you have.

Comment: @Mike i've added the reason to my question please read the italic part at the end

Comment: @hretic So basically you're adding more junk on top of someone else's junk (no offense). Think about the future of your app. Is this as far as you want to develop it, or are you going to want to keep developing or growing it? If you might want to keep developing it, the earlier you fix mistakes like these, the less pain you're going to have in the future when they become a huge snowball of hurt. If this is as far as you're going to develop it, well. "It's not good, but it works" is about as good as you're going to get.

Comment: @hretic Of the 3, if I absolutely had to choose, I would go with 1 simply because it allows you to put the actual admin ID in. But then again, that's merely opinion.

Comment: What are the primary keys of the `users` and `admins` tables?

Comment: @Mike i absolutely understand what you're saying , i never accept to work on someone elses project but its a favor for a friend im not even going to put it in my resume ! thanx for the advice

Comment: @DanMan primary keys are `id`

Comment: @hretic Adding a "level" column to "users" and setting a default level for users to something less than whatever the lowest level is currently for admins, and then moving the "admins" to the "users" table would not be hard to do. The only side effect is that the admins' user ids will change, which could potentially affect things, like if you put the id in the URL. Then just refactor the parts of your code that mention admins.

Comment: 1. Give the current design DDL if you are asking about changing/expanding it. 2. Google SO re subtyping in database design. Have separate tables for admin- & user- specific info, while other things' tables have what  person-with-an-id (user or admin) is associated with them. (Avoid NULL; subtype tags are ok.) 3. Be clear about what info you want to record. Do you or do you not care about which admin is associated with a book? What *is* the association? "P listed B"? "U listed B or U = -1 and an admin listed B"? PS -1: Bad idea. (Also often NULL.) PS *Views* offer old tables in terms of new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to agree with Ross. There are only two things you can do with a poorly designed database -- make it a little worse every time you need to make changes or bite the bullet and improve the design.

Ok, the database is a year or two old and has lots of data. That, if you do it right, is not a problem.

```
create table OwnerTypes(
  ID    char( 1 )     not null primary key -- contains 'U' or 'A'
  Name  varchar( 16 ) not null -- contains 'User' or 'Admin'
  Other [type] -- if needed
);

create table Owners_(
  ID       int       not null  -- could be auto generated
  TypeID   char( 1 ) not null references OwnerTypes( ID ),
  Username varchar( 32 ) not null,
  Password varchar( 32 ) not null,
  constraint PK_Owners primary key( ID, TypeID )
);

create table Users_(
  ID       int       not null primary key,
  UserType char( 1 ) not null check UserType = 'U',
  Email    varchar( 128 ) not null,
  Name     varchar( 32 ) not null,
  constraint FK_Users_Owners foreign key( ID, UserType )
    references Owners_( ID, TypeID )
);

create table Admins_(
  ID       int       not null primary key,
  UserType char( 1 ) not null check UserType = 'A',
  Level    smallint  not null,
  constraint FK_Admins_Owners foreign key( ID, UserType )
    references Owners_( ID, TypeID )
);
```

**Note:** MySQL accepts but does not enforce check constraints. You'll have to do that with trigger or other code.

You'll notice I ended three of the table names with an underscore. That is my way of naming a table that is not expected to be directly accessed by application code. As you still have the problem with all kinds of existing scripts and app code that expects to see a Users and an Admins table, we are going to provide that access through views.

```
create view Users as
  select  o.Username, o.Password, u.Email, u.name
  from    Owners o
  join    Users u
      on  u.ID = o.ID
      and u.userType = o.TypeID;
```

Now you have a database object named `Users` that provides the data in the form expected by the apps. Do the same thing with `Admins`. Finally, write triggers on the views that will intercept DML and perform the operations as needed to maintain the data in the actual form. The app developers don't even have to know anything changed.

This way, you can update your database as needed but allow existing code to continue to operate as before.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for help on here violates best practices, therefore, the advice given would be similar to **"how to kludge a system to work in a horrible manner".** In this case, the advice I would give to you would be to use your best judgment.

There is nothing stopping you from adding a column for each entity defined in your system. You could also normalize your kludge and add a EntityID to that table, linking back to a BookEntity table that then defines an EntityType, however, that would be adding another level of abstraction on top of a bad design. In the circumstances you provided, I would say yeah, add another column.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're giving is still not good enough to do it like you suggest. You'll just hate yourself later on.

If the primary keys of the `users` and `admins` tables don't overlap, then I'd merge the tables, and add one additional column like `usertype`, indicating where each entry originated from.

If they do overlap, you just make the primary key consist of both the `id` and the `usertype` column. That way the same `id` can exist multiple times, but it'd still be unique in combination with the `usertype`.

Once this is done, you'd add either just the `id` column to the `books` table, or include the 'usertype' as well.